# How to change path of resouce image in XCode?

Tags: iphone, resources, localization

I am localizing the images, as localizing to chinese simple it will create folder name as zh-Hans.Iproj by default but chinese won't be recognized if folder name is not zh_CN.Iproj so I created manually folder with name "zh_CN.Iproj", now I copied all images from zh-Hans.Iproj to zh_CN.Iproj folder, but in XCode I am unable to change the path of images, I can't not delete and import again because it is an hierarchy like this

```
mmSettings.png
 >>mmSettings.png (English)
 >>mmSettings.png (Chinese)
 >>mmSettings.png (Spanish)
```

Here path of english file is **en.Iproj** and for spanish the folder is **es.Iproj**

These both are by defaul created by XCode as you click + sign for localizing your images, but when you click **zh_CN.lproj/mmSettings.png** and make chinese, it will create folder name as **zh-Hans** for simplified chinese, that is not recognized until it won't be **zh_CN.Iproj**, so I created this folder, but unable to change path of images from XCode,

Help

If someone is not clear about the question, let me know , I do explain more

IMAGE LIKE THIS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can't localize images like this. my way is:

1, in the Localization.string , link your image name, such as:

buttonImage = "image1_en.png" in your english file and

buttonImage = "image1_zh.png" in your chinese file and ...

2, in your code, use it like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithName:NSLocalizeString(@"buttonImage","image for button")];
```